# Do compiler warnings has any impact on Web Application performance

Tags: java, performance, jsp, web-applications, javac

Being a lazy programmer i usually overlooks compiler warnings both in **Jsp** and **Java** code.

I can justify **JSP** warning by thinking that missing JavaScript, validations and other stuff could be resolved at run-time. but needs to be sure.

but i am always teased by **Java** warnings like

- [GENERIC Type] is a raw type. References to generic type [GENERIC TYPE] should be parameterized.
- The field [FIELD NAME] is never read locally.

and many many more.

My Question is that

### Do warnings has any impact on performance ?

- If not, then why compiler keep shouting?Is helping us to write good code?
- If may be, then which types of warnings should not be neglected?
- If yes, (Memory could be) then how deep it is?

Comment: *"I can justify JSP warning by thinking that missing JavaScript, validations and other stuff could be resolved at run-time."* JSP = JavaServer Pages. They have nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: JSPs may contain JavaScript, which in turn may generate errors or warnings already on the compile phase (e.g. when the JS is not enclosed in CDATA tags on XHTML pages and when using ampersands).

Comment: `The field [FIELD NAME] is never read locally.` is an Eclipse warning. Not a compiler warning.

Comment: "Is helping us to write good code?"  Yes.

Comment: If you ignore `[GENERIC Type] is a raw type. References to generic type [GENERIC TYPE] should be parameterized.`, your application may throw errors and not work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for replies, i am more interested in JVM behavior against warnings, like we initialize a field in class and keep it unused in application life, this could make application memory inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

> If not, then why compiler keep shouting? Is helping us to write good code?

definitely so. Most of those warnings are "best practices... not practiced" :)
Why using raw type if Java now offers generics, for example?

You may have your reasons to neglect them. And then many IDEs gives you the possibility to turn off those warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler warnings are almost always alerting you of potential unintended behavior or unnecessary code. In all practicality, they do not impact runtime performance of the code. Writing non-performant code (much, *much* easier to do) is a far greater worry.

As far as unused local variables are concerned, it's possible that some compilers will optimize this and simply not allocate the memory for assignment. The statements which produce the result, however, still need to be executed as they may include side effects.

There are ways to turn off various type of compiler warnings that you acknowledge aren't important to your code (the "should declare a serialVersionUID" warning, for instance, is a common one that's often not particularly applicable). You can do this with the @SuppressWarnings annotation per class / method / field, or you can do it once at the compiler level by supplying options to it.